# Phonegap/Cordova too many logs CordovaLog Web Console

Tags: cordova, logging, cordova-2.0.0

I am using the latest phonegap/cordova version 2.1. and I am getting too many logs in eclipse logcat:
everything is logged twice using f.e.

```
console.log("test")

CordovaLog   test
Web Console  test
```

This could be disabled by a filter in eclipse, but there must be smarter solution.

Comment: did you try to build you app in the release mode. i think that should solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks. I think it is not a suitable solution because it takes too much time to use the wizard every time. Have you tested it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should edit the following entry

```
<log level="DEBUG"/>
```

in the `config.xml` file.

Available values are **ERROR**, **WARN**, **INFO**, **DEBUG**, **VERBOSE** (default=ERROR)

Setting to `ERROR` you will see the least amount of log messages.

Answer (score 3):

Take  a look at this

http://css.dzone.com/articles/setting-console-debugging

UPDATE :

After a lot of hard work, I found out that is the BEST and the ONLY solution available right now to debug your javascript code with phonegap is to open the HTML file in the browser and use its console to debug it IE (Google Chrome)
, Also, JSFiddle's JSLint feature will help you find almost all the bugs in your code

Best Regards

Comment: thnak you. seems like there is no solution yet, only filtering in eclipse

Comment: I would love to see a full implementation of phonegap in Eclipse/Zend Studio, it is hard to debug the code without a good solution to find out whats wrong

Comment: Agreed. Debugging Phonegap apps is a nightmare

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use weinre:

http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre-docs/latest/

install it via node.js and run a weinre-server with following command:

```
weinre --boundHost -all-
```

then link the weinre debugger in your index.html (replace localhost by your actual IP):

```
<script src="http://127.0.0.1:8080/target/target-script-min.js#anonymous"></script>
```

Weinre will show you a console and explorer similar to developer tools in browsers.
You can reach it on the your PC by calling `http://localhost:8080` in your browser.

EDIT: see this summary of debug methods as well: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/Debugging-in-PhoneGap

Answer (score 0):

Things might have changed a bit now.

Use the below now:

```
<preference name="loglevel" value="VERBOSE" />
```